# Showing and hiding an overlay over the entire app not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am using a singleton in order to show and hide overlay viewControllers from any place in the app when needed. This works mostly, but sometimes (mostly when running on a real device, rarely also on the simulator) hiding the ViewController also hides the ViewController below (in the case below `FeedViewController`) which should not be influenced by this overlay at all, and should stay "below" the overlay when its displayed.

I have captured the view hierarchy just before hiding the overlay when it works and when it breaks (removes the underlaying ViewController). In both cases the code was the exact same, I suspect it has something to do with when the overlay is presented due to asynchronicity..

**Is there a way to ensure correct display and dismissal of such a overlay, that is save, no matter when it is shown or hidden? Or what is going wrong here?**

**Bad View Hierarchy** that dismisses also the FeedViewController once the Overlay is hidden:
[image]
**Good View Hierarchy** (just before dismissal) looks like this:
[image]

This is the code:

```swift
import UIKit

class OverlayHelper {
    
    static let shared = OverlayHelper()
    
    private var overlayControllers: [UIViewController] = []
    
    private init() {}
    
    func presentOverlayViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) async -> Bool {
        
        let result = await MainActor.run { () -> Bool in
            /* this has the same issue, the view hierarchy is even "worse" i.e. the overlay seems to be "behind" the FeedViewController
             if let windowScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene,
               let window = windowScene.windows.first {
                window.rootViewController?.addChild(viewController)
                window.addSubview(viewController.view)
                viewController.didMove(toParent: window.rootViewController)
                overlayControllers.append(viewController)
                return true
            }*/
            if let navigationController = SceneDelegate.shared?.appCoordinator.navigationController {
                navigationController.addChild(viewController)
                navigationController.view.addSubview(viewController.view)
                viewController.didMove(toParent: navigationController)
                overlayControllers.append(viewController)
                return true
            }
            return false
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func hideOverlayViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) async -> Bool {
        guard let index = overlayControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) else {
            return false
        }
        await MainActor.run {
            viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)
            viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
            viewController.removeFromParent()
            overlayControllers.remove(at: index)
        }
        return true
    }
}
```